# What are the APIs exposed by OKTA

Tags: okta, okta-api

I have used one API in OKTA  `" mydomain.okta.com/api/v1/authn "`

Am looking for other such APIs that OKTA expose, I couldn't find any list in any documentation.
Can anyone get the source of the open APIs that can be used to consume ( say example - user profile details ) in okta. Am looking for other APIs that are available to manage Groups, Users, Roles, Apps, etc

Rigin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okta API documentation is available at http://developer.okta.com

Specifically, Users API is at http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/users.html

Comment: Along with that take a look at [setting up Postman for Okta](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/getting_started/api_test_client.html). The API test client is a good place to start and see how the calls are made and the response you should receive.